# My java class implementation of XOR encryption has gone wrong

Tags: java, encryption, xor

I am new to java but I am very fluent in C++ and C# especially C#. I know how to do xor encryption in both C# and C++. The problem is the algorithm I wrote in Java to implement xor encryption seems to be producing wrong results. The results are usually a bunch of spaces and I am sure that is wrong. Here is the class below:

```
public final class Encrypter {

    public static String EncryptString(String input, String key)
    {


        int length;
        int index = 0, index2 = 0;
        byte[] ibytes = input.getBytes();
        byte[] kbytes = key.getBytes();
        length = kbytes.length;
        char[] output = new char[ibytes.length]; 
        for(byte b : ibytes)
        {
            if (index == length)
            {
                index = 0;

            }
            int val = (b ^ kbytes[index]);
            output[index2] = (char)val;
            index++;
            index2++;
        }


        return new String(output);
    }
    public static String DecryptString(String input, String key)
    {
        int length;
        int index = 0, index2 = 0;
        byte[] ibytes = input.getBytes();
        byte[] kbytes = key.getBytes();
        length = kbytes.length;
        char[] output = new char[ibytes.length]; 
        for(byte b : ibytes)
        {
            if (index == length)
            {
                index = 0;

            }
            int val = (b ^ kbytes[index]);
            output[index2] = (char)val;
            index++;
            index2++;
        }


        return new String(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: not all characters are printable

Comment: Encrypted data should be treated as binary, its no longer text.

Comment: if you encrypt then decrypt a text, will it output correctly?

Comment: @Peter Well there's always Windows-1252 - the bastard child of base64 ;)

Comment: Or ISO-8859-1  Much better to use a `byte[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Java are Unicode - and Unicode strings are not general holders for bytes like ASCII strings can be.

You're taking a string and converting it to bytes without specifying what character encoding you want, so you're getting the platform default encoding - probably US-ASCII, UTF-8 or one of the Windows code pages.

Then you're preforming arithmetic/logic operations on these bytes. (I haven't looked at what you're doing here - you say you know the algorithm.)

Finally, you're taking these transformed bytes and trying to turn them back into a string - that is, back into characters. Again, you haven't specified the character encoding (but you'll get the same as you got converting characters to bytes, so that's OK), but, most importantly...

Unless your platform default encoding uses a single byte per character (e.g. US-ASCII), then not all of the byte sequences you will generate represent valid characters.

So, two pieces of advice come from this:

1. Don't use strings as general holders for bytes
2. Always specify a character encoding when converting between bytes and characters.

In this case, you might have more success if you specifically give US-ASCII as the encoding.  EDIT: This last sentence is not true (see comments below). Refer back to point 1 above! Use bytes, not characters, when you want bytes.

Comment: To expand on this answer, `byte[]` is more appropriate than `String` for storing bytes.  To write bytes to stdout, use `System.out.write(myByteArray)`.

Comment: ASCII chars also assume that the 8th bit is 0, which is obviously not true for binary data. And lots of extended pages (OEM pages or whatever MS calls them.. ASCII + the upper 128 chars with some other signs) also don't handle the whole range. Afaik the only encoding that MAY handle all 8bit input is Windows-1252 and even that is specified to leave a few positions empty. Windows has just always assigned some control signs there so it should generally work. But in general: The second to last sentence is the important thing: Don't use strings to store byte data.. if you really have to use base64

Comment: +1 to Voo's comment.  ASCII is not an holder for bytes.  ASCII defines only 128 points, not 256.

Comment: @dty: *"At least in Java, the US-ASCII character set is an 8-bit character set."* [sic]   Not at all.  ASCII (US-ASCII) defines 128 code points.  ASCII is typically represented on a byte whose highest bit is set to zero.  And it's definitely an *"8-bit character set"*.

Comment: One liner to show that Java doesn't consider bytes above 127 to be part of the US-ASCII charset (hope SO doesn't mess the formatting of that one): *System.out.println( 0x80 == (new String(new byte[]{(byte) 0x80}, "US-ASCII")).getBytes("US-ASCII")[0
] );*  shall print *false*.   Replace the two 0x80 by anything from 0 to 127 and it shall print true.  Characters above 127 become '?' because they're definitely **not** part of US-ASCII: it's impossible.  ASCII is a 7 bit charset (typically represented on 8 bits, but that's something entirely different).

Comment: Well now, isn't that interesting. I've never observed that behaviour before, but maybe I've never used characters when I meant bytes! ;-) So, I retract the last sentence of my reply.

Comment: @dty: I haven't enough rep yet to edit your answer but you should remove the last sentence because it won't work to use US-ASCII: every byte above 127 will become 0x3F (which the '?' character, used by Java to indicate that US-ASCII cannot make sense of a character whose codepoint is above 127).

Comment: Yup, you have to play around with [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) and [CharsetEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) to have it throw an exception instead of simply replacing characters. Personally, I think that should have been the default. Now you have something that silently fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you use non-ascii strings as keys you'll get pretty strange results. The bytes in the kbytes array will be negative. Sign-extension then means that val will come out negative. The cast to char will then produce a character in the FF80-FFFF range.

These characters will certainly not be printable, and depending on what you use to check the output you may be shown "box" or some other replacement characters.